# android garbage collector, freeing objects inside objects

Tags: android, garbage-collection, arraylist

I'm very curious about how this thing works inside Android. I have a class with two List<> inside, instantiated at runtime and loaded with objects created while reading some data, I want to know what happens with those Lists in this situation:

1. Class A has List B and List C with many other initialized objects
   inside.
2. Another different class get a reference of List C from a
   method of Class A, like  `public List<myObject> GetList()`.
3. Somewhere in code, Class A is no longer used and application
   signals that to garbage collector, setting object to null.

What happens with my List C that is referenced by other object?  What happens with Object class A?

I've tried to track garbage collector with Logcat running apk in debugger step-by-step but no luck at all. Sometimes it frees memory, sometimes not, I couldn't pinpoint any specific behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is any object, that still has a path to root, containing a reference to another object, the referenced object will not be garbage collected.  So if you create object A, that has a sub object A1.  Then create object B and through what ever means pass a reference to A1 to object B.  Even when object A is GC'd A1 will not be because object B still holds a reference.  (In your example, A & B will be gc'd... C will not)

You can experiment with the mechanics behind garbage collection by telling the system explicitly to perform a collection at certain times with a `System.gc();` call.  Also you can override the finalize in object to see exactly when the given object is collected.:

```
   @Override
   protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
      try {
         Log.d("Learning about GC", "My Object has been GC'd." + this);         
      } finally {
         super.finalize();
      }
   }
```

You can learn a lot through experimenting with objects, references, finalize and explicit calls for gc().  I would remove the overridden finalize call when you done testing.

Comment: Although Pixie's answer its correct too, I'm tending to choose Gregg's for such a great advice, really worth it. I just discovered how to correctly dispose of my objects to increase performance, thanks a lot for this!

Comment: @ruhalde: I hope you're not going to use finalization to increase performance because it can only decrease performance. Here's a good article about GC: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html.

Comment: I never suggested using finalize for anything other than a learning tool.  It most definitely is not the place to perform any clean up or required functionality, but can be a great way to get some hands on learning about how GC works.  As I mentioned in my original post, I would also recommend removing the finalize call when you are done experimenting/testing.

Comment: I'm not forcing object destruction, I've just put a Log.d message there and tuned my signaling to GC, that is, I mark an object for destruction with an  object=null assignment in some strategic places of my code, really works.

Answer (score 3):

The object of class A will be garbage collected during the next GC-cycle. List B will be GC'ed too. And List C will not be GC'ed because it can be reached from GC roots.

Answer (score -1):

By default java creates an object by reference instead of by value. So, in this case if the garbage collector would pick up and empty all A B C and the then the other class that referenced C would be empty, since it didnt create a duplication of the class, it just referenced it.