# Android recycling resources after fragment deletion

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-memory

I'm adding and removing certain Fragments on the fly. My question is if I remove a fragment with something like:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(myFragment).commit();
```

how can I ensure that Android DOES remove this fragment and all of its resources (images especially) from the memory? Because for me it seems even though the fragment itself is removed from the layout, it remains in memory until its parent activity is finished.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to test if any java object gets recycled is to override the finalize method (See accepted answer to [android garbage collector, freeing objects inside objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108834/android-garbage-collector-freeing-objects-inside-objects)
)

What that could look like: in your fragment class (or any other class of interest)

```
    @Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    Log.i("Fragment Recycled",this.toString());
    super.finalize();
}
```

The same could be done for any other object of interest.Once the finalize method is overriden, you could look in the log cat to see if the Fragment does get recycled or not. I hope this helps.